# React Native swipe left to open a page like Instagram

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, swipe, gesture

I have a react native application with bottom tab view. and I want to add the feature when in the first page I want to swipe left and open the Chat page I have.

I tried `react-native-gesture-handler` but it doesn't provide me with the functionality I want. I feel like its more for list items to swipe

I basically want to swipe left to open the chat page that I already have

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **react-navigation** library for creating the tab navigators as you told.

**Check out the official docs for more information.**

[React Navigation Material Top Tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator)

[React Navigation Bottom Tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/)

**Check out the below example code.**

```
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

import ChatScreen from '../screens/ChatScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';
import NotificationScreen from '../screens/NotificationScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/ProfileScreen';

const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notification" component={NotificationScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator tabBar={() => null}>
      <TopTab.Screen name="Tabs" component={BottomTab} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MainNavigation;
```